# How to show/hide div at the bottom of a page (sticky footer toggled on and off)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a changelog at the bottom of my page, which can be toggled on (shown) and off (hidden, only a small arrow or "Changelog" button so it can be shown again)

This is the code for the div (Full page view is more accurate):

```css
.index_changelog {
    background-color: #222222;
    font: normal normal bold 2em/normal "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(64, 126, 196);
    resize: none;
    border: black;
    border-bottom: blue 1em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 95%;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class = "footer">
          <textarea class="index_changelog" allign="center" readonly="readonly">
    SOME TEXT HERE
    SOME TEXT HERE
    SOME TEXT HERE
    SOME TEXT HERE
    SOME TEXT HERE
          </textarea>
      </div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a changelog a reference img would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you could do it. Using JQuery, simply toggle a class that causes the footer to be positioned within the body element.

Something like

```
$('.showMe').click(function(){
    $('.index_changelog').toggleClass('bottom');
});
```

http://codepen.io/nallenanderson/pen/ONEpRb

You can style it up a little bit by adding to your .index-changelog

```
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Your answer is correct as well as hmd's, but I need the button to stick at the bottom of the page and appear only when the changelog is hidden

Comment: How to position the button on top of the `.index_changelog` class, so only the button appears on the bottom of the page when `.index_changelog` is hidden

Comment: I updated the codepen for you. Is there a reason why you needed to use a textarea? I changed that and added opening and closing buttons.

Comment: I ended up using `addClass(/this is a class with css: bottom: -250px;/)` and `removeClass(/this is a class with css: bottom: 0px;/)` functions to move the changelog down, and almost the same - `addClass(/this is a class with css: bottom: 0px;/)` and `removeClass(/this is a class with css: bottom: -250px;/)` functions to move the changelog up but still your answer was pretty useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By using Jquery's method [.slideToggle()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=slideToggle) you can do this easily. Don't forget to include Jquery Library:

```css
.index_changelog {
    background-color: #222222;
    font: normal normal bold 2em/normal "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(64, 126, 196);
    resize: none;
    border: black;
    border-bottom: blue 1em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 95%;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="$('.footer').slideToggle('slow');">Changelog</button>

<div class = "footer">
          <textarea class="index_changelog" allign="center" readonly="readonly">
    SOME TEXT HERE
    SOME TEXT HERE
    SOME TEXT HERE
    SOME TEXT HERE
    SOME TEXT HERE
          </textarea>
      </div>
```

Comment: As per my understanding you want to toggle your Sticky Footer by using some Button or Arrow, so If I'm right, you can achieve this like my example. You can style the button as well. And if it helped you, don't forget to mark as Correct :)

Comment: Your answer is correct as well as nallenanderson's, but I need the button to stick at the bottom of the page and appear only when the changelog is hidden

Comment: @ValentinPetkov by placing your this `<button>` into your footer, you can style your footer and button as the way you want to see this. I'm not that much good in CSS otherwise I will love to do that for you :)